# What is the name of this part of a matrix?

Tags: matrices, terminology

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&0&0\\0&a_{22}&0\\0&0&a_{33}\end{pmatrix}$, $B = \begin{pmatrix}0&0&a_{13}\\0&a_{22}&0\\a_{31}&0&0\end{pmatrix}$

Here the elements $a_{11},a_{22},a_{33}$ lies along a particular line and that line is called diagonal line of the matrix. My question is that "what is name of the line along which the elements $a_{13},a_{22},a_{31}$ lies." I think that this type of question are trivial and doesn't match with the terms and conditions of this site.

Comment: You can represent them as vectors on the axis.

Comment: I think it's called "anti-diagonal". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-diagonal_matrix

Comment: ["The top-right to bottom-left diagonal is sometimes described as the minor diagonal or antidiagonal."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal#Matrices).

Comment: diagonal, secondary diagonal

Answer (score 1):

It's called an anti-diagonal. A couple of people have already said this in the comments section.